# how to use camera capacitor pluging using react

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, camera, capacitor

I want to open the camera of my pc via capacitor camera pluging within my react code but it fail. There is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Plugins, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/core';

const App = () => {

  const { Camera } = Plugins;

  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState();
  const takePhoto = async () => {
    console.log("Launch function");
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
    console.log(image.webPath);
    setPhoto(image.webPath);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {photo ? <img src={photo} alt="test camera" /> : <span>There is no picture yet.</span>}

      <button onClick={takePhoto}>Camera</button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and this is the error that I get:
[that is my console screeshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIDmE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just install a load the ui component used to take the photo.
In the src/index.js I just add the following:

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';
defineCustomElements(window);
```

that is my final resutl:

```
import React from 'react';
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

defineCustomElements(window);

const app = (
    <App />
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```